# Unable to install yap with Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, yap

I want to install yap on my Mac (macOS 10.13 High Sierra) but I can't using Howebrew.

I've tried the command

```
$ brew install yap
```

but I get the error

```
$ Error: No available formula with the name "yap"
```

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Yap is no more available from Homebrew. [According to one of the Hombrew comitter](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/18999):

> We do no package this software, so you will need to get it from its website (https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/) and build it from source.